# Can I change the iCal calendar server?

Tags: android, calendar.app, webdav

From a quick look at an Android powered Samsung Galaxy Tab, I've got the impression that there is no way to change that the built-in calendar syncs to Google servers.

Is that so? Has Google hard-wired Google services/servers into Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the default Android calendar application is heavily tied into Google services. To my knowledge there is no way to use other providers with it. But I might be mistaken.

Either way, there are a [myriad of calendar applications](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=calendar&c=apps) for Android. Maybe you'll find something more suited for your requirements.

Comment: Sad to hear, as Android for me was the "open" (= customizable alternative to iOS). From my first test drive of an iPad, it seems, there, you can change the iCal server on the default application easily. Can you confirm this? 1:0 for Apple?

Comment: @isync: Well, my Android also supports Exchange calendars in addition to Google calendars, but that's as far as it goes. But I'm sure you have other providers in mind. Sadly, I have no iPhone, so I can't confirm anything in that regard. And, yes, Android is very open. This is just the *default* Calendar application. As I said, you can install many others and completely replace the default. Additionally, the exact calendar application you receive can differ depending on the phone manufacturer and the installed Android version. Try before you buy ;)